# calculating derivative in R using D function in mosaic package

Tags: r

I installed mosaic package available in R to calculate derivative by typing install.packages('mosaic'). I created a function using makeFun and then i tried to calculate derivative in the following way

```
y1 <- makeFun(a +b *x  ~x, a=2, b=2)
dy1.dx <- D(a + b* x ~ x, a=2, b=2)
dy1.dx
```

but the console shows

```
" dy1.dx <- D(a+b*x~x, a=2, b=2)
Error in D(a + b * x ~ x, a = 2, b = 2) : unused arguments (a = 2, b = 2)"
```

How can I correct it?

Comment: Please read the documentation of the function and do `example("D")` !

Comment: I read but couldn't get how to solve this problem. I used "quote" and that work but how to put value of constant in that

Comment: Your example is not reproducible; `y1 <- makeFun(a +b *x  ~x, a=2, b=2)` gives `Error in makeFun(a + b * x ~ x, a = 2, b = 2) : 
  could not find function "makeFun"` **Please read** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: This is because mosaic package is to be installed by typing install.packages('mosaic').

Comment: Please put additional information in your question - **not in a comment**, i.e. **edit your question**:  https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48761689/edit

Comment: Sorry for the mistake, I am new to programming and stackoverflow

Answer (score 1):

using the base R's `stats` package. No need to install additional packages like `mosaic`.

`D` will give the derivative of expression, so using `expression()` function, we create an expression and pass it to the `D` function.

Then `eval` will evaluate the expression and `substitute` will substitute values of `a` and `b` in the expression.

get the derivative for an expression with respect to x:

```
stats::D(expression(a + b * x), "x")
# b
```

evaluate the expression after substituting with values in the derivative.
`b` is substituted with the value 2.

```
eval(substitute( stats::D(expression(a + b * x), "x"), list(a=2, b = 2) ))
# [1] 2
```

Another example:

```
stats::D(expression(a + a*b * x), "x")
# a * b
eval(substitute( D(expression(a + a*b * x), "x"), list(a=3, b = 2) ))
# 3 * 2
eval(eval(substitute( D(expression(a + a*b * x), "x"), list(a=3, b = 2) )))
# 6
```

Comment: sorry sir, I am new to R and a learning slowly. Can you suggest me how i can correct my codes it if I have mosaic package installed.

Comment: I do not have mosaic package installed on my system.

Comment: I added some explanation to follow it. If you want to learn more, please read the documentation page by type `?D`  or `?expression`

Answer (score 0):

`D` used in your example is from `library(mosaicCalc)` and not from base stat.  Install and call the library. Your function works normally.

```r
require(mosaicCalc)
#> Loading required package: mosaicCalc
#> Warning: package 'mosaicCalc' was built under R version 3.6.3
#> Loading required package: mosaicCore
#> Warning: package 'mosaicCore' was built under R version 3.6.3
#> Registered S3 method overwritten by 'mosaic':
#>   method                           from   
#>   fortify.SpatialPolygonsDataFrame ggplot2
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'mosaicCalc'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     D
dy1.dx <- D(a + b * x ~ x, a = 2, b = 2)
dy1.dx
#> function (x, a = 2, b = 2) 
#> b
```